Geodesics on a Riemannian surface
I am studying Riemannian geometry and I am facing a problem with geodesics: if $S=(S,g)$ is a Riemannian surface, then $\gamma: I\rightarrow S$ is the parametrization of a geodesic if and only if, by definition, $\nabla_{\gamma'(t)}\gamma'=0$, that is, the vector field $\gamma'$ is parallel along $C=\gamma(I)$. This should imply that $||\gamma'(t)||_g$ (the norm of the tangent vector, with respect to the metric $g$ defined on the surface) is constant. I am trying to prove it evaluating the derivative of $||\gamma'(t)||_g$ and using geodesics' equations, but without any success.
Do you have any suggestion?
Here my calculations:
let $\omega: D\rightarrow S$ be a local parametrization of $S$ and let $\gamma(t)=\omega(x_1(t),x_2(t))$ be the parametrization of a geodesic (then $x_k''(t)=-\sum_{i,j}x_i'(t)x_j'(t)\Gamma_{ij}^k$ for $k=1,2$). Then $||\gamma'(t)||_g^2=\sum_{i,j}g_{ij}x_i'(t)x_j'(t)\Longrightarrow$ $\frac{d}{dt}(||\gamma'(t)||_g^2)=\sum_{i,j}(x_i''(t)x_j'(t)g_{ij}+x_j''(t)x_i'(t)g_{ij}+x_i'(t)x_j'(t)(\frac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial x_1}x_1'(t)+\frac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial x_2}x_2'(t)))$.
From this expression we can substitute geodesics'equations, but I am afraid it would be unhelpful.
Thanks for any help!

Perhaps some details about "I am trying to prove it evaluating the derivative of $||\gamma′(t)||g$ and using geodesics' equations, but without any success." would yield more helpful responses.

Hint: without any local parametrization of your surface, go back to the very first properties of the Levi-Civita connection to compute the derivative of $|\gamma' |^2 = g(\gamma',\gamma')$

Unfortunately I do not know anything about Levi-Civita connection...the only possible explanation I can give is actually a physical explanation: if we consider $\gamma(t)$ as the parametrization of the trajectory of a free particle moving on the surface (a free particles on a Remannian manifold moves on the geodesics of the manifold), then the scalar velocity should be constant due to the conservation of energy (because the particle is free, so its Lagrangian coincides with the kinetic energy, which is $T=\frac{1}{2}||\gamma'(t)||_g^2$), but it is not a geometric proof

What definition of $\nabla$ do you have? It must somehow be related to the metric and you should be able to show that $\langle X,Y\rangle{}’ = \langle \nabla_{\gamma’}X,Y\rangle + \langle \nabla_{\gamma’}Y,X\rangle$ for any vector fields $X,Y$ defined along $\gamma$. That’s the geometry.

How is it possible to prove a property of a geodesic, if you don’t use the definition of a geodesic in your calculation? Please substitute the geodesic equation into your calculation.

I probably found the answer, tell me if I am wrong: $||\gamma'(t)||g^2=g(\gamma'(t),\gamma'(t))$. Now, taking the derivative of this quantity with respect to the parameter $t$ means calculating the derivative along the direction of $\gamma'$, that is $\frac{d}{dt}g(\gamma'(t),\gamma'(t))=\frac{\partial}{\partial \gamma'}g(\gamma'(t),\gamma'(t))$. For the properties of covariant derivative, this is equal to $g(\nabla{\gamma'(t)}\gamma',\gamma'(t))+g(\gamma'(t),\nabla_{\gamma'(t)}\gamma')$. If $C$ is a geodesic, then, by definition, $\nabla_{\gamma'(t)}\gamma'=0$, so $||\gamma'(t)||_g$=const.

Yes, that’s correct.
